# c++, insert only numbers (double) in a QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt4, qtablewidget

I'm creating a sort of little spreadshirt and I need to insert only numbers in all the cells of a column.

Is there anyway to do this just with the tablewidget or do I need to "fill" table with LineEdit and then restict on some way the LineEdit input?

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After perusing some of the documentation, it looks like you might have to use `QLineEdit` widgets and [`setValidator`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qlineedit.html#setValidator) to a [`QDoubleValidator`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qdoublevalidator.html). This is a fairly simple way to accomplish what you want, but for more complex spreadsheets you might need to get into something like a [`QTableView`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtableview.html) and get down and dirty in [Qt's Model/View framework](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/model-view-programming.html).